# android table vertical column divider

Tags: android, android-tablelayout, divider

I am trying to add a vertical divider between columns in android table layout and tried multiple solutions but not have worked so for. This my table code an image of the result

For some reason the view is taking up an entire column to display the divider even when the width is mentioned

Table code

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/item_code"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/red_" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/item_desc"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </TableRow>

    <View
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="@color/red_" />

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="SFT001" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/red_" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Full table" />

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

[image: table with divider added]

Answer (score 0):

I found it easier to use background on the individual cells to achieve dividers.

e.g. create a drawable like below called right_border.xml

```xml
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/red" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:right="3dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

(this is a red rectangle with a white rectangle over the top but leaving 3dp of the red exposed)

Then on the Cell (TextView)

```xml
<TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/item_code"
            android:textStyle="bold" 
            android:background="@drawable/right_border"/>
```

Other drawables with rectangles and combinations of rectangles can give you a full border or any side(s).

Comment: Yes this works but the alignment of the all the rows is askew